# Send email after successful user registration using meteor js

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, meteor-accounts

I want to add the email functionality to my application. I have added the email package and followed steps according to the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email_send) provided

I want when the user registers itself, an email should be sent after successful registration.

Here is what I tried:

server/smtp.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  smtp = {
    username: 'abc@gmail.com',   // eg: server@gentlenode.com
    password: 'abc123',   // eg: 3eeP1gtizk5eziohfervU
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',  // eg: mail.gandi.net
    port: 25
  }

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
});
```

here is my server/emp_details.js where i have called methods. the following code is placed inside `Meteor.methods()`:

```
sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    //actual email sending method
    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      text: text
    });
  }
```

And finally I called the method at client side as shown:

```
Template.register.onRendered(function()
{
    var validator = $('.register').validate({
        submitHandler: function(event)
        {
            var email = $('[name=email]').val();
            var password = $('[name=password]').val();
            var empProfile = Session.get('profileImage');
            console.log(empProfile);
            Accounts.createUser({
                email: email,
                password: password,
                profile: {
                    name:'test',
                    image: empProfile
                },
                function(error)
                {
                    if(error)
                    {
                        if(error.reason == "Email already exists.")
                        {
                            validator.showErrors({
                                email: "This email already belongs to a registered user"
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                        'alice@example.com',
                        'abc@example.com',
                        'Hello from Meteor!',
                        'This is a test of Email.send.');
                        Router.go("home");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to use this email functionality properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest an alternate solution? Add a hook to Accounts.onCreateUser() on the server side to send the email:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    Meteor.call(
        'sendEmail', 
        'admin@yoursite.com',
        user.profile.email, //use the path to the users email in their profile
        'Hello from Meteor!',
        'This is a test of Email.send.'
    );
});
```

Are you actually using gmail? The SMTP port for google is 465 I believe, not 25. Confirm that your email sending works outside of meteor using that config, and then attempt it in Meteor. I also believe google limits the number of emails sent via SMTP to 99 per day so be careful with that. If you want to verify a users email address, use the built in email verification system in the `accounts` package.

Comment: thank you Brett, it worked, just a game of user.profile.email

Comment: Please suggest an alternate solution also. I want to try that too.